# Multiple Counts() in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing query that returns a result set that looks like this:

```
ID    ContactID     ContactName    Amount
-------------------------------------------
1        42           Joe          $5.00
2        42           Joe          $6.00
3        96           Tim          $1.00
4        96           Tim          $3.00
5        96           Tim          $9.00
```

Now, in each row, I need a count by ContactID

```
ID        Count    ContactID     ContactName    Amount
--------------------------------------------------------
1          2        42           Joe          $5.00
2          2        42           Joe          $6.00
3          3        96           Tim          $1.00
4          3        96           Tim          $3.00
5          3        96           Tim          $9.00
```

Here's the current query:

```
SELECT 
    ls.LeadSalesID, 
    ls.SoldToContactID,
    c.FirstName, 
    ls.Amount
FROM 
    LeadSales ls
    JOIN Contacts c ON c.ContactID = ls.SoldToContactID
WHERE
    ls.LeadSalesCreditStatus = 1
```

I've tried GROUPING BY all all the columns in the SELECT and then adding a COUNT(ls.SoldToContactID), but the COUNT column returns all 1's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `count` window function.

```
SELECT 
    ls.LeadSalesID, 
    ls.SoldToContactID,
    c.FirstName, 
    ls.Amount,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY c.ContactID) as cnt
FROM 
    LeadSales ls
    JOIN Contacts c ON c.ContactID = ls.SoldToContactID
WHERE
    ls.LeadSalesCreditStatus = 1
```

Comment: Wow.  That's it.  Thanks!  I'l have to read up on PARTITION BY so I understand what it's doing.